# find minimum value through recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I tried the following code in python but it gives error of list index out of range. Can anyone help

```
def mini2(x):
    n=0
    min1=x[n]
    if min1>x[n+1]:     
        min1 = x[n+1]
        mini1(x[(n+1):])
    else:
        min1<x[n+1]
        mini1(x[(n+1):])
```

Comment: What is `mini1`? Anyhow, probably just a typo. Try your code on [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) to better understand your problem. What happens if the list finally contains only one element? And what does the function return?

Answer (score 1):

Observations of your code:

- Base case is missing - what if the list is empty? How do you handle it?
- Function does not return any value - during recursion, the function executes locally. How to capture the returned value?
- Typo for function calls

Here is my solution similar to your implementation with changes as mentioned above:

```
def minimum(x):
    n = 0
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]

    min1 = x[n]
    min2 = minimum(x[(n+1):])

    if min1 > min2:     
        min1 = min2
    
    return min1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def mini2(x):
    n = 0
    min1 = x[n]

    # termination case when only on element is left in the list
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]

    # cut down list and calls function again
    if min1 > x[n+1]:
        # deletes element n because it is greater then the next one
        del x[n]
        return(mini2(x))
    else:
        # deletes element n + 1 because it is greater then the last one
        del x[n + 1]
        return(mini2(x))


x = [9, 4, 12, 420, -30, 1337, 2, 18, 720]

print(mini2(x))
```

This is based on your code. To cut down the list with each call of the function.

Without deleting (now slicing)

```
def mini2(x):
    n = 0
    min1 = x[n]

    # termination case when only on element is left in the list
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]

    # cut down list and calls function again
    if min1 > x[n+1]:
        # deletes element n because it is greater then the next one
        # del x[n]
        return(mini2(x[1:]))
    else:
        # deletes element n + 1 because it is greater then the last one
        # del x[n + 1]
        return(mini2(x[:1] + x[2:]))


x = [9, 4, 12, 420, -30, 1337, 2, 18, 720]

print(mini2(x))

print(x)
```

Comment: Why do you delete elements? The OP's question doesn't mention any reference to deleting elements from `x`??

Comment: @Stef you are right i did not think about changing the original list. I made a second version that doesnt change the original version. Thx.